# Javascript fillable pdf form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need assistance generating a fillable pdf form with Javascript that a user can either email or download offline then fill it in, not all user details will be filled offline some will be generated with the pdf.

I do know how to generate a normal pdf document with Javascript just not the one that a user can fill in offline and save.

I don't know if you can guide me on what to do or what to check to achieve this?. Unfortunately, I don't have any code for this at this stage because I am stuck.

Comment: have you checked out any JS PDF libaries like https://parall.ax/products/jspdf ?

Comment: I don't think so there is any library to do so, you just need to create a good PDF template that user can understand that it is a fillable form. user just need to open it in a good editor which allow him to write o PDF.